# Laravel 8x: phpunit Expected status code 204 but received 429. Failed asserting that 204 is identical to 429

Tags: laravel, api, automated-tests, phpunit

I'm trying to test 1000 requests related to an API service:

```
   for($i = 0;$i<1000;$i++)
    {
        $response = $this->put('/api/update',$data);
        $response->assertStatus(204);
    }
```

unfortunately when I get to 50 requests the test fails for 429.

I tried to run the test with --process-isolation too but I get the usual results

Comment: `app/Http/Kernel.php` in you can increase `throttle:60,1` based on your req.

Comment: i didn't understand how to change this: 'api' => [
            'throttle:api',
            \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\SubstituteBindings::class,
        ], @KamleshPaul

Comment: `throttle:api` is 1 mint you can make 60 req. if your remove this then limit will be reoved

Comment: i get             'throttle:1200,1', and i fix @KamleshPaul

Comment: I assume you use the usually app bootstrapping with testing, what do you achieve by testing your api 1000 times? This seems very synthetic and does not achieve any real life benefits imo, since the app will not have any http server involved.